# Is there a way to uninstall multiple packages with pip?

Tags: python, pip, xargs

I am attempting to remove all of the installed "pyobjc-framework"-prefixed packages. I have tried the following:

```
% pip freeze | grep pyobjc-framework | xargs pip uninstall
```

but this barfs because each pip uninstall requires confirmation (perhaps a way to bypass this would be a solution).

Please help before I have to break down and uninstall each of these manually! Nobody wants that.

Comment: How about Windows?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Your command should actually work if you add the `-y | --yes` flag to pip   :-)

> -y, --yes             Don't ask for confirmation of uninstall deletions.

Possibly:

`% pip freeze | grep pyobjc-framework | xargs pip uninstall -y`

Comment: Bingo. -y is the flag I needed. I also need xargs to pass a single argument at a time so my final command looks like this: `% pip freeze | grep pyobjc-framework | xargs -n 1 sudo pip uninstall -y` Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Redirect the grep output to a new file and run.

```
pip uninstall -r <file name>
```

works I think.

```
pip freeze | grep pyobjc > packages_to_remove.txt
sudo pip uninstall -y -r packages_to_remove.txt
```

Comment: er, sorry. `pip freeze | grep pyobjc > packages_to_remove.txt; sudo pip uninstall -y -r packages_to_remove.txt` should do it. Note, the -y flag must come first when also using the -r flag and a file argument. Doh.

Answer (score 10):

I always use this:

```
pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

Comment: Without `grep` it should remove all your pip packages.

Answer (score 9):

Easiest way. use remove all `torch` related packages for example:

```
pip uninstall `pip freeze | grep torch`
```

Comment: pip uninstall -y `pip freeze | grep torch`

Answer (score 3):

Just prepare those packages as list:

```
pip uninstall <list of requirement> -y
e.g.:
pip uninstall  termcolor, imgviz, matplotlib, PyYAML, qtpy, Pillow, colorama, PyQt5, numpy -y
(Some version of pip require to remove commas, s. below)
pip uninstall termcolor imgviz matplotlib -y
```

For example: Uninstall package with its dependence with pip in three steps:

1. show dependence list
2. remove the package
3. remove list of its dependence (copy it from 1.)

##### For detail:

```
 1. pip show <package>

    e.g.:
    pip show labelme
    ...
    Requires: termcolor, imgviz, matplotlib, PyYAML, qtpy, Pillow, colorama, PyQt5, numpy
    ...

 2. pip uninstall <package>
    e.g.
    pip uninstall labelme

 3. pip uninstall <list of requirement> -y
    e.g.:
    pip uninstall  termcolor, imgviz, matplotlib, PyYAML, qtpy, Pillow, colorama, PyQt5, numpy -y
```

Comment: I doubt you can place commas to separate the names. Are you 100% sure of that?

Comment: yes, it work at least with ubuntu 20.04, python 3.9 and pip 20.3.3

Comment: OK, maybe, not sure why it works. Not sure why you would want to recommend this unusual notation either. Why not just stick to standard notation?

Comment: In some case it important to do such details: e.g. quicker while looking what is in requirement file

Comment: Fails with bash ... 
$ pip uninstall xlsxwriter, xlrd
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'xlsxwriter,'

Answer (score 1):

greping `pip freeze` returned:

```
Usage:   
  pip uninstall [options] <package> ...
  pip uninstall [options] -r <requirements file> ...

no such option: -e
```

So I did it with `pip list` instead:

```
$ pip list | grep tempest | xargs pip uninstall -y

Uninstalling neutron-tempest-plugin-0.0.0:
  Successfully uninstalled neutron-tempest-plugin-0.0.0
Uninstalling octavia-tempest-plugin-0.0.0:
  Successfully uninstalled octavia-tempest-plugin-0.0.0
Uninstalling tempest-19.0.1.dev152:
  Successfully uninstalled tempest-19.0.1.dev152
```

Answer (score 1):

Do `pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)`

Answer (score 1):

###### You can uninstall packages that start with certain characters using a combination of `pip freeze`, `grep`, and `awk` commands.

Here's an example for uninstalling packages that start with `PyQt`:

- if you want to see the packages before:

```
pip freeze | grep -E '^PyQt'
```

- then uninstall:

```
pip freeze | grep -E '^PyQt' | awk -F'==' '{print $1}' | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

This will remove every package that starts with `PyQt`.

###### If you want to uninstall all packages at once, you can do so with the following:

```
pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

This will remove every package from pip.