# Python Pip Uninstall Multiple Packages

Tags: python, pip, conda

whats the way to remove all packages in python 2.7 at one time, i've installed lot of packages and messed it up, so instead of manually uninstall them one by one, i want to look for a method that can get rid of those packages automatically, so i can start clean sheet again. Thank you in advance. By the way, im using windows 10 and has pip,conda installed in python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to uninstall multiple packages with pip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406123/is-there-a-way-to-uninstall-multiple-packages-with-pip)

Comment: thank you, that works smoothly

Answer (score 0):

use the all flag:

```
conda uninstall -n environment --all
```

if you are in the environment and its active:

```
conda uninstall --all
```