# How do you uninstall multiple packages with pipenv?

Tags: python, windows, pipenv

I have ended up installing multiple Azure packages that I don't need. I have seen solutions of how to uninstall them [using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406123/is-there-a-way-to-uninstall-multiple-packages-with-pip?noredirect=1&lq=1) but not with pipenv. Here's a sample of the packages I'd like to remove (there's about 60 packages):

```
azure-mgmt-advisor==1.0.1
azure-mgmt-applicationinsights==0.1.1
azure-mgmt-authorization==0.50.0
azure-mgmt-batch==5.0.1
```

I am new to python (and consequently to pipenv). Would appreciate any help offered.

Comment: Based on [this article](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#environment-management-with-pipenv): Assuming you can do `pipenv install [package names]`, and "pipenv uninstall supports all of the parameters in pipenv install", you should be able to run `pipenv uninstall azure-mgmt-advisor azure-mgmt-applicationinstights ...`

Comment: @Redline The article was a big help to get more information, thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply run `pipenv uninstall package1 package2 package3`, and pipenv will uninstall those packages from your virtual environment.

Answer (score 5):

If someone landed on this answer while looking to uninstall ALL packages in the env, you can run `pipenv uninstall --all`